# How to change Storage Class on AWS S3 object via java sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

I am new to AWS, I need to set Storage Class for an existed object in s3 bucket. How can I change the storage class of an Object in S3 using the java SDK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is no need to use deprecated method in any case.
in my case in need to update an existing object:

```
   AmazonS3Client s3Client =  (AmazonS3Client)AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(clientRegion)
                .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                .build();
  CopyObjectRequest copyRequest = new CopyObjectRequest(sourceBucketName, sourceKey, destinationBucketName, destinationKey)
        .withStorageClass(StorageClass.ReducedRedundancy);
        s3Client.copyObject(copyRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks pretty simple with [changeObjectStorageClass](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#changeObjectStorageClass-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.StorageClass-):

```
AmazonS3Client s3Client = (AmazonS3Client)AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withRegion(clientRegion)
                    .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                    .build();

PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName,
                                                fileObjKeyName, new File(fileName));
ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
metadata.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
request.setMetadata(metadata);
s3Client.putObject(request);

s3Client.changeObjectStorageClass(bucketName, fileObjKeyName,
                                  StorageClass.ReducedRedundancy );
```

The only strange part is that you need to use the `changeObjectStorageClass` on an instance of `AmazonS3Client` - the version on the interface `AmazonS3` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated AWS for Java V2 response. This code placed the object in a Glacier Deep Archive storage class.

```
 public static String copyBucketObject (S3Client s3, String fromBucket, String objectKey, String toBucket) {
        CopyObjectRequest copyReq = CopyObjectRequest.builder()
            .sourceBucket(fromBucket)
            .sourceKey(objectKey)
            .storageClass("DEEP_ARCHIVE")
            .destinationBucket(toBucket)
            .destinationKey(objectKey)
            .build();

        try {
            CopyObjectResponse copyRes = s3.copyObject(copyReq);
            return copyRes.copyObjectResult().toString();

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return "";
    }
```